# How does 'using' directive work with template member functions

Tags: c++, templates, crtp, using-directives

I am using the CRTP and the base class has a template function. How can I `use` that member function in a templated derived class?

```
template <typename T>
struct A {
  int f();
  template <typename S>
  int g();
};
struct B: public A<B> {
  int h() { return f() + g<void>(); } // ok
};
template <typename T>
struct C: public A<C<T>> {
  // must 'use' to get without qualifying with this->
  using A<C<T>>::f; // ok
  using A<C<T>>::g; // nope
  int h() { return f() + g<void>(); } // doesn't work
};
```

*** Edit ***
An earlier question, [Using declaration for type-dependent template name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15423283/using-declaration-for-type-dependent-template-name), including the comments, suggests this isn't possible and might be an oversight in the standard.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to solve the problem with `using` statement (it should look something like `using A<C<T>>::template g;`, but this code does not compile with my compiler). But you may call `g<void>` method in one of the following ways:

- `this->template g<void>()`
- `A<C<T>>::template g<void>()`

See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords) for details about the dark side of using `template` keyword.

Comment: Yes, your other two statements are how I would access g without using `using`, but they're both pretty cumbersome! I was hoping a magic incantation of `template` let me avoid them.